# I need help with 2009 Buick Lucerne- Engine and Oil

Tags: engine, oil, buick, damage

I have a 2009 Buick Lucerne.  I have recently realized it has been dripping oil. Thought it was another car and it is not a lot of oil.  Anyway, this prompted me to check the oil level.  I usually do this every so often anyway, but fell out of the habit within the past several months due to a lot going on (no excuse, I know).  I never had to add oil in the past when checking between changes with my previous vehicle and I am getting to know this current Buick as quite a high maintenance B*.   I still like the car a lot though, and so, am willing to give it some time and benefit of doubt.  To the point (two days ago) - When I checked the oil level it seemed empty.  There was oil all over the dipstick  before I cleaned it off but after cleaning it off is when it looked empty to me.  There was only oil on the side edge of the stick about an inch or two long.  I put the stick back in and went for another person for second opinion.  I do have trouble reading these sometimes. When I pulled the stick out this second time, oil was all over it again.  I clean it it off, reinserted it and got the oil only on the edge again.  So I put in some oil.  I had to put in two quarts to get it to where it should be.  Now I am very worried I ruined my car.  There were never any symptoms or warnings that my car was low in oil.  No oil light warning.... nothing.  Also I am due for an oil change which I had planned for this Wednesday on my day off.  Then, driving home from work last night, my change engine oil light came on.  Coincidence?  Have I damaged my car?  I am not driving it anywhere now until I change the oil.

Answer (score 1):

The change oil light comes on when certain parameters are met by the computer. Things like time, miles and driving conditions. It has nothing to do with your current dillemna. Sounds like you have been driving around 2 quarts low. That is low enough to do engine damage if driven too long like that, but also may have done little or no damage. If you don't know a good repair facility, try and find one through recommendations. Tell them your concerns and they will look a little into it to see if you have anything to worry about. This shouldn't cost much. Do not take it to a quick oil change store as they generally do not have the expertise to advise on this. I suspect that once your oil is changed, you will be alright as long as you check your oil once a week.